# windows-installer check if repair needed

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am installing a set of file using an MSI generated via WiX toolset.
Is there a way to know if any of the file installed were manually modified after installation?
I know MSI has repair option but this I would expect would overwrite the file. I would rather have an earlier stage that only detects that the installation is corrupted and ideally on which file.

Comment: Is this in preparation for patching or something like that?

Comment: It may happen that someone does an hot fix on a script on a machine were i originally installed some code. I would be able to detect that someone changed something and potentially know what.